# Java two timers

Tags: java, multithreading, csv, timer, cassandra

I have two timer, that schedule two tasks:

```
public ReWrite() throws InterruptedException {
    timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask CSVTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            readFromCSV();
        }
    };
    TimerTask mailTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            checkStatus();
        }
    };
    timer.schedule (CSVTask, 0l, 1000*60*60);
    timer.schedule (mailTask, 60000l, 1000*60*10);
}
```

**readFromvCSV()**

1. Finding all CSV files in folder except the last one
2. Reading all data from them and write to CassandraDB (or if can't - to the last file in folder)
3. Delete all CSV files (except the last one)

**checkStatus()**

1. Finding all CSV files in folder and take file size of the last one
2. If file size > 1 mb, sending email

It working at first, while data was about few rows, but when it comes to thousands - i got this error message:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at handler.emergency.ReWrite.WriteToCassandra(ReWrite.java:197)
at handler.emergency.ReWrite.lambda$ReadFromCSV$1(ReWrite.java:137)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at handler.emergency.ReWrite.ReadFromCSV(ReWrite.java:129)
at handler.emergency.ReWrite.access$000(ReWrite.java:21)
at handler.emergency.ReWrite$1.run(ReWrite.java:56)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Maybe I got this error by accessing file with two task at the same time?

Possibly I can just write two different classes with they own timers and tasks: One with read\write functions and Second for read\Email, but I'm interesting in solving problem in that way with two timers/tasks.

What I need for this? Another Async Thread?

*Sorry for all mistakes, my 1st post*

**UPDATED:** Post for inattention, sorry. Error was from wrong CSV data.

Comment: It tells you that the error is at `at com.academmedia.stat.handler.emergency.ReWrite.WriteToCassandra(ReWrite.java:197)`

Comment: Yes, sorry, just didn't saw that trace row. It seems sometimes brain and eyes need rest *_*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that your WriteToCassandra (method?) is causing the problem. Without the full code we cannot help you. Also locking a file while reading/writing to it should be considered but to be honest, I didn't do a lot of file I/O so others might give you better advice

Comment: Thats right, error was in Write method - just mistake in InputData - CSV was from some other project..

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace it seems that the code tries to iterate over a collection. If elements from the collection are removed during iteration, then iteration may fail when proper means are not taken. It may be what happens in your case.
The above scenario seems plausible, as you mention transferring source rows to one of two possible destinations (Cassandra or file), which means that you probably delete the already-transferred rows from the source.
This does not explain yet, though, why the error is visible only with larger files. The information and code abstraction that you have provided seems too far from the source of the error to be sure.

Comment: By using an Iterator<Class> i = collection.iterator() it is possible to create a while(iterator.hasNext()) loop in which you can call iterator.next(). Then you can call iterator.remove() inside the loop to remove the element from the collection while continuing to iterate over it. :)

Comment: @xxtesaxx Edited my post to incorporate your comment. I have meant that deletion during iteration fails if not done **properly**, as the stack trace may suggest here. Yes, you are right that it is generally possible, just care must be taken.